# SAL Query error: Unexpected keyword. (near INNER JOIN) Unrecognized statement type. (near INNER JOIN)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, stripe-payments

the first post on here so apologies if I haven't formatted things properly or if I'm not entirely clear, but I was wondering if someone may be able to assist with an error I'm facing currently.

To give some context, I'm trying to run an SQL query through my phpMyAdmin, in order to fix a customer error we were receiving on-site, after changing our Stripe accounts
WooCommerce support had provided me with the following link:
https://woocommerce.com/document/stripe-fixing-customer-errors/#section-3

However, when I try this in my phpMyAdmin, I get the following error:

> Unexpected keyword. (near INNER JOIN)
>  Unrecognized statement type.
> (near INNER JOIN)

[SQL Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN4ui.png)

The query that they had asked me to run is seen here:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_usermeta`
WHERE meta_key IN ( '_stripe_customer_id', '_stripe_source_id', '_stripe_card_id' );
DELETE tokenmeta FROM `wp_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta` tokenmeta
INNER JOIN `wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens` ON `wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens`.`token_id` = tokenmeta.`payment_token_id`
WHERE `wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens`.`gateway_id` = 'stripe';
DELETE FROM `wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens` WHERE gateway_id='stripe';
```

I had spoken to support, who had said that the query is absolutely fine and they could run it on their end, and my developer friends are also a little unsure about this.

Is someone able to shed some light on this and see if I'm doing something wrong? There is a good chance that there is a simple change that's needed that's gone over my head, but I'm just not too sure what it is!

Comment: It's not possible to see the code in the image..I cannot reproduce your error , the syntax is correct..Can you run the queries successfully individually?

Comment: Hi P.Salmon, sorry, the full code can be seen here:
I had tried to run the queries individually, I think it only effects the ones with the text 'INNER JOIN'

DELETE FROM `wp_usermeta`
WHERE meta_key IN ( '_stripe_customer_id', '_stripe_source_id', '_stripe_card_id' );
DELETE tokenmeta FROM `wp_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta` tokenmeta
INNER JOIN `wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens` ON `wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens`.`token_id` = tokenmeta.`payment_token_id`
WHERE `wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens`.`gateway_id` = 'stripe';
DELETE FROM `wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens` WHERE gateway_id='stripe';

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon, apologies, I can see you weren't notified in my previous comment. I've provided the entire code in that entry. It seems that the queries with the 'INNER JOIN' are the culprits. I just don't know why it's doing this! If you are able to advise, you'd be an absolute saint. Appreciate your help so far